# Golang empty Location on Mac OSX when parsing time

Tags: json, macos, serialization, go, time

When decoding a timestamp field from JSON into a `struct` on my local OS X machine, the `Location` of the `time.Time` field is "empty" rather than UTC. This is problematic for me running unit tests locally (vs. on a CI server where the `Location` is being set correctly to be UTC).

Here's the example code: https://play.golang.org/p/pb3eMbjSmv

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Ignoring the err just for this example's sake!
    parsed, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2017-08-15T22:30:00+00:00")
    fmt.Printf("String(): %v\n", parsed.String())
    fmt.Printf("Location(): %v\n", parsed.Location())
}
```

which outputs

```
String(): 2017-08-15 22:30:00 +0000 +0000
Location():
```

So while the offset of the `time.Time`'s `Location` appears to be correct, its timezone name is just an empty string. Running in on other machines (and The Go Playground) give the expected "UTC" location.

When I run that on my machine, I see

```
TimeField.String(): 2017-08-15 22:30:00 +0000 +0000
TimeField.Location():
```

So while the offset of the `time.Time`'s `Location` appears to be correct, its timezone name is just an empty string. This is using Go 1.5:

```
go version go1.5 darwin/amd64
```

Comment: To simplify, the `json` part is actually irrelevant: the UnmarshalJSON method is just a wrapper around time.Parse using the RFC3339 format string:
`time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2017-08-15T22:30:00+00:00")`

Comment: Thanks @djd, updated description of question to simplify and just use `time.Parse`.

Comment: [This code](https://golang.org/src/time/format.go#L1015) in `time/format.go` seems like it could be a likely culprit, but it doesn't necessarily explain why the behavior is different on my local mac os x machine vs. the CI server we use (Linux) or whatever Go Playground uses.

Answer (score 0):

I find same behavior using my current setup on Mac and I suspect it will be same behavior on Linux (not sure through)

```
$ go version
go version devel +31ad583 Wed Aug 10 19:44:08 2016 +0000 darwin/amd64
```

To make it more deterministic, I suggest using a custom json Unmarshal like so:

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "strings"
  "time"
)

type Time struct {
   *time.Time
}

func (t *Time) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
  const format = "\"2006-01-02T15:04:05+00:00\""
  t_, err := time.Parse(format, string(b))
  if err != nil {
      return err
  }
  *t = Time{&t_}
  return nil
}

type Example struct {
  TimeField *Time `json:"time_field"`
}

func main() {
  inString := "{\"time_field\": \"2017-08-15T22:30:00+00:00\"}"
  var ex Example
  decoder := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(inString))
  decoder.Decode(&ex)
  fmt.Printf("TimeField.String(): %v\n", ex.TimeField.String())
  fmt.Printf("TimeField.Location(): %v\n", ex.TimeField.Location())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are right. On The Go Playground the `Local` is set to `UTC` inside that sandbox:
Try this working sample code on <kbd>[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SkD5BgYCxE)</kbd>:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.Version(), runtime.GOARCH, runtime.GOOS) //go1.7 amd64p32 nacl

    parsed, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2017-08-15T22:30:00+00:00")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("String(): %v\n", parsed.String())
    fmt.Printf("Location(): %v\n", parsed.Location())
}
```

output on The Go Playground:

```
go1.7 amd64p32 nacl
String(): 2017-08-15 22:30:00 +0000 UTC
Location(): UTC
```

And try it on your local system, output `Location()` is empty.

---

You may use `utc := parsed.UTC()` with the location set to UTC, like this working sample code <kbd>[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6lvElTGx3M)</kbd>:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.Version(), runtime.GOARCH, runtime.GOOS) //go1.7 amd64p32 nacl

    parsed, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2017-08-15T22:30:00+00:00")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("String(): %v\n", parsed.String())
    fmt.Printf("Location(): %v\n", parsed.Location())
    utc := parsed.UTC()
    fmt.Printf("String(): %v\n", utc.String())
    fmt.Printf("Location(): %v\n", utc.Location())
}
```

---

Also You may use `time.ParseInLocation(time.RFC3339, "2017-08-15T22:30:00+00:00", time.UTC)`, like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.Version(), runtime.GOARCH, runtime.GOOS) //go1.7 amd64p32 nacl

    parsed, err := time.ParseInLocation(time.RFC3339, "2017-08-15T22:30:00+00:00", time.UTC)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("String(): %v\n", parsed.String())
    fmt.Printf("Location(): %v\n", parsed.Location())
}
```

So the `Location()`  will be `UTC`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @djd for pointing out that we can skip all the JSON/struct decoding business; the key issue is with `time.Parse`.

The same issue comes up here where the `Location` is "empty" rather than UTC (I would've expected UTC based on the docs: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse

> In the absence of a time zone indicator, Parse returns a time in UTC.

---

<sub>This answer was taken from the question as of [revision 6](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39090669/6).</sub>